# How to improve my custom unique_ptr class? I want to realize that derived class can cast to base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, unique-ptr

I realize a unique_ptr class by myself as below, and use it to manage another class:

```
namespace mcj {
template <typename CallbackT>
class unique_ptr {
 public:
  unique_ptr(CallbackT* ptr = nullptr) : ptr_(ptr) {
    std::cout << "unique_ptr normal constructor" << std::endl;
  }

  unique_ptr(unique_ptr<CallbackT>&& ptr) {
    if (ptr_) {
      delete ptr_;
      ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
    ptr_ = ptr.release();
    std::cout << "unique_ptr move constructor(unique_ptr<CallbackT>&& ptr)"
              << std::endl;
  }

  unique_ptr<CallbackT>& operator=(unique_ptr<CallbackT>&& ptr) {
    if (ptr_) {
      delete ptr_;
      ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
    ptr_ = ptr.release();
    std::cout << "unique_ptr move operation(=)" << std::endl;
    return *this;
  }

  unique_ptr(const unique_ptr<CallbackT>& other) = delete;
  unique_ptr<CallbackT>& operator=(const unique_ptr<CallbackT>& other) = delete;

  ~unique_ptr() {
    delete ptr_;
    ptr_ = nullptr;
  }

  CallbackT& operator*() { return *ptr_; }
  CallbackT* operator->() { return ptr_; }
  CallbackT* get() const { return ptr_; };

  CallbackT* release() {
    if (ptr_) {
      CallbackT* temp = ptr_;
      ptr_ = nullptr;
      return temp;
    }
    return ptr_;
  }

 private:
  CallbackT* ptr_;
};
}  // namespace mcj
```

I call `mcj::unique_ptr` like this, A is base base class and B is derived class:

```
mcj::unique_ptr<A> CastToBase() {
  return mcj::unique_ptr<B>(new B);
}
mcj::unique_ptr<A> h = CastToBase();
```

But an error occurs:

> /Users/chaojie.mo/Documents/test/test/main.cpp:42:10: error: no viable
> conversion from returned value of type 'unique_ptr' to function
> return type 'unique_ptr'   return mcj::unique_ptr(new B);
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ /Users/chaojie.mo/Documents/test/src/callback_utils.h:11:3: note:
> candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
> 'mcj::unique_ptr' to 'A *' for 1st argument   unique_ptr(CallbackT*
> ptr = nullptr) : ptr_(ptr) {   ^
> /Users/chaojie.mo/Documents/test/src/callback_utils.h:15:3: note:
> candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
> 'mcj::unique_ptr' to 'unique_ptr &&' for 1st argument
> unique_ptr(unique_ptr&& ptr) {   ^
> /Users/chaojie.mo/Documents/test/src/callback_utils.h:35:3: note:
> candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
> 'mcj::unique_ptr' to 'const unique_ptr &' for 1st argument
> unique_ptr(const unique_ptr& other) = delete;

Can someone tell me how to improve `mcj::unique_ptr` to support that a derived class can cast to a base class?

Comment: I'm confused:  You said you "realize" `unique_ptr`.  By that it appears you mean you wrote your own version.  Why would you do that?  Why not use `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: For the purpose of learning，I realize a simple unique_ptr by myself

Comment: Your move constructor has undefined behaviour as it uses `ptr_` which is uninitialised

Comment: You need to implement constructor 6: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr (and probably the matching assignment operator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo<B>` is not a subclass of `foo<B>` in c++. Google 'contravariance and covariance in c++ smart pointers',

You will have to extract the pointer cast it and create a new unique_ptr to return